# Save GeoPandas geodata frame into a file including symbology to open in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, geopandas, geopackage

I'm working in Python with the GeoPandas library, and I would like to save GeoDataframes into shapefiles or geopackage files with symbology.

I've read that in QGIS, it is possible to save the symbology as part of the .gpkg file itself, so I was wondering whether this can be done programmatically in Python.

In the documentation of GeoPandas, I did not see any information regarding how to do this. Does someone have any insight on this?

Comment: are you sure about the symbology bit? [Check this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377634/qgis-geopackage-export-of-layer-symbology).

Comment: What type of file is being stored in the .gpkg that holds the symbiology information? In qgis you can save symbiology as a .qrl or .qml - [diffeences](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/424250/saving-orthomosaic-tiff-data-with-symbolization-changes-using-qgis/426699#426699).

Comment: Try looking into [Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/tutorials/basictutorial/qml.html) for this.